# First order logic tableaux with multiple quantifiers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I find very confusing to understand how combined qualifiers might expand on a tableaux. While for $\exists x\ p(x)$, I would just create a new term, a, and for $\forall x\ p(x)$ I would use an existing one, I find it very confusing what should happen when mixing both.

So I drew this table. Am I correct in saying the the third one will stop and the fourth won't? Am I missing some other edge cases?

[image]

Comment: You are right; with the case $\forall x \exists y$ you generate a sort of "loop": every time you instantiate $\exists y$ you need a *new* constant. Thus, you must apply $\forall x$ to it, and this produce a new instance of $\exists y$, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you run out of steps to use in case 3, but the branch in case 4 can go on for ever.

But to be pernickety (just in case your mode of presentation does indeed represent your thinking) ...

No, no, no, you **never** instantiate two quantifiers at once in a tableau (which is what you seem to be doing). You are only allowed, at a given step, to instantiate the **outermost** quantifier. Look at the rules (in my logic text or any other tableau-based textbook).

So if a wff is of the form $\forall x\varphi(x)$ then you instantiate with a new name $a$  to derive $\varphi(a)$ -- and that still applies if $\varphi$ itself starts with a quantifier. Once you have $\varphi(a)$ you then apply whatever rule is now appropriate.

Thus the tableau might go

$$\forall x\exists y Rxy$$
$$\exists yRay$$
$$ Rab$$
And now you could (if you want) continue
$$\exists yRby$$
$$ Rbc$$
But the intervening steps (not indicated in any way in your trees) are essential.